# Trying to hide HTML page before javascript animation loads(super newb edition)

Tags: javascript, animation, load, flicker

I know what you're thinking, not this again, right?

Here's my site: http://mydesignfeti.sh/

As you will see the browser loads the body & all of its content then the javascript animation loads. All I want is for the animation to load without having to see the content load beforehand. If you're lacking an imagination just refresh the page or click the logo in the top left to see how I want the page to load.

I've tried toggling the container div's class display using javascript, but apparently I was doing it wrong.

Suggestions? Answers? Laughs?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the code you were using that was "doing it wrong" and we can tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not super familiar with how Adobe Edge works, but the basic idea is you will need to either:

1. Make your initial html/css match the animation base state.
2. Hide your animated divs initally, using css `display: none`, and add a second state to your animation to display all of the elements (eg `display: block`) before sliding them back on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the html set the container div property `style="display: none;"`, this will hide the html elements until the javascript animation gets loaded.

Comment: Tried it, but it just stayed hidden.